# Compare two files

Tags: shell, text-processing

I want to compare two files in which the data is delimited by a pipe `|`. Both the files have the same results but only few fields might vary.

File 1:

```
A|B|C|D
```

File 2:

```
A|B|F|D
```

I want to compare two files field by field, that is, by omiting column 3, my result should show zero difference.

I want to find the difference, if any. apart from the few columns that I mention.

Comment: PLease include sample output and what you have tried yourself...

Comment: `join file1 file2` doesn't do the job?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cut` to remove unwanted columns. From the man page:

```
   -d, --delimiter=DELIM
          use DELIM instead of TAB for field delimiter

   -f, --fields=LIST
          select  only  these  fields;   also  print any line that contains 
          no delimiter character, unless the -s option is specified

   --complement
          complement the set of selected bytes, characters or fields
```

You can use this to create temporary files, which you can compare using `diff` like that:

```
cut -d'|' -f 3 --complement <file1 >file1.tmp
cut -d'|' -f 3 --complement <file2 >file2.tmp
diff file1.tmp file2.tmp
```

Comment: You can do without temporary files: `diff <(cut -d'|' -f 3 --complement file1) <(cut -d'|' -f 3 --complement file1)`